# Generically setting JsonProperty (NewtonSoft) for retreiving data from an API

Tags: c#, json, .net, web, httpclient

I'm currently working on a project in which I need to be able to retreive data from an API and then get certain parts of the data. The getting the data bit has all gone well (with a HttpClient) but now I need to find a way to get certain elements from this data. Therefore I wish to use NewtonSoft to get the data as classes.

The image below shows my code. The JsonProperty should be generic which is unfortunately not possible because it throws the error "An object reference is needed for the non-static field".
The reason I want this to be able to change is that each response has the same structure but the names in the JSON are different, which means that the code will break. I've read about CustomPropertyResolvers but I've not managed to get one to work.

In the below example there is a "avg" value in the DataPointer class. This is depended on the endpoint that is being called. There are also cases in which this variable is called "count" and is of type integer. I'm thinking about getting to this problem with the help of nullable variables. But for now the JsonProperty issue is the main problem.

Can anybody give me an example or point me in the right way for fixing my problem?

```
 public class DataMapper
{

    public async Task<string>MapData(HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage)
    {
        string responseContent = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(responseContent);

        return null;
    }

    public class DataPointer
    {
        public double avg { get; set; }
    }

    public class Segment
    {
        public DateTimeOffset start { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset end { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("requests/duration")]
        public DataPointer endValue { get; set; }
    }

    public class Value
    {
        public DateTime start { get; set; }
        public DateTime end { get; set; }
        public string interval { get; set; }
        public List<Segment> segments { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public Value value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Below is an example of a response that I'm working with. Note that the "requests/duration" part is the flexible part. This is different for each endpoint in the API, which is why I need the JsonProperty to be flexible/generic

```
    {
    "value": {
        "start": "2021-07-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "end": "2021-07-04T00:00:00.000Z",
        "interval": "P1D",
        "segments": [
            {
                "start": "2021-07-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                "end": "2021-07-02T00:00:00.000Z",
                "requests/duration": {
                    "avg": 2072.02
                }
            },
            {
                "start": "2021-07-02T00:00:00.000Z",
                "end": "2021-07-03T00:00:00.000Z",
                "requests/duration": {
                    "avg": 4250.72
                }
            },
            {
                "start": "2021-07-03T00:00:00.000Z",
                "end": "2021-07-04T00:00:00.000Z",
                "requests/duration": {
                    "avg": 260.87
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: You to post your json string example at least

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I've added one

Comment: Thanks, I see "request/duration" and avg . What name can be changing. I can' t see any change still?

Comment: I have edited the example to hopefully make it more clear. But how it works is as follows: 

The requests/duration part of the response changes per request. I need to set a JsonProperty with this value so that the response gets mapped (without the JsonProperty attribute a mapping error occurs). So I need to be able to change this JsonProperty dynamically based on the request.

The calls are made to the Application Insights API which adds part of the request in the response, the "request/duration" is an endpoint in this API. This could also be a large amount of other endpoints.

Comment: You need to post a clear example of what the `requests/duration` could be. As of now, it's always a `double` (not an `int`, as the `avg` property Type is set to). BTW, `start` and `end` properties are of Type DateTimeOffset.

Comment: I'm sorry I've had the classes generated, apparently that didn't go too well. For the endpoints that I'm currently using the "avg" is either an integer or a double. Also, "avg" could be "count" in certain endpoints. I'm thinking about fixing that issue with nullable variables. @Jimi

Comment: Why don't you use a `Dictionary<string, double>`? I mean change in: `[JsonProperty("requests/duration")] public Dictionary<string, double> endValue { get; set; }` and remove `DataPointer`. Note that `Value ` is not a good name for a class.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! it is indeed possible to drop the DataPointer class for a dictionary. However I still need that JsonProperty in a very static way. When a different endpoint is called this property can change. By using "requests/duration" the code will break on any endpoint in which the response doesn't contain this value. Do you happen to know how I can fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It was tested in VS and working properly

```
var jsonOrig=...your json

 var deserializedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(jsonOrig);

            foreach (var dict in deserializedJson.value.segments)
            {

                var segment = new Segment();

                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> entry in dict)
                {
                    
                    switch (entry.Key)
                    {
                        case "start":
                            segment.start = (DateTime)entry.Value;
                            break;

                        case "end":
                            segment.end = (DateTime)entry.Value;
                            break;

                        default:

segment.endValue =JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataPointer>(entry.Value.ToString());
                            
                            break;
                    }

                    
                }
                deserializedJson.value.segmentsList.Add(segment);
            }

   deserializedJson.segments=null;

   return deserializedJson;
```

classes

```
  public class Root
    {
        public Value value { get; set; }
    }

    public class Value
    {
        public DateTime start { get; set; }
        public DateTime end { get; set; }
        public string interval { get; set; }
        
        public List<Dictionary<string, object>> segments { get; set; }
        public List<Segment> segmentsList { get; set; } = new List<Segment>();
    }
    
    
    public class Segment
    {
        public DateTime start { get; set; }
        public DateTime end { get; set; }

        public DataPointer endValue { get; set; }
    }

    public class DataPointer
    {
        public double avg { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! this has fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

This might be the idiomatic way of doing it using the NewtonsoftJson **[JsonExtensionData](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeExtensionData.htm)** property.

It captures any unassigned properties in a dictionary which can then be inspected and assigned in the **OnDeserialized** method.

```
public class Test02 {
    public static void test(){
        var json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("json.js");
        var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
    }
    public class DataPointer
    {
        public double avg { get; set; }
    }

    public class Segment
    {
        public DateTimeOffset start { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset end { get; set; }
        public DataPointer endValue { get; set; }


        [JsonExtensionData]
        private IDictionary<string, JToken> _additionalData;

        [OnDeserialized]
        private void OnDeserialized(StreamingContext context)
        {
            // "request/duration" is not deserialized to any property
            // and so it is added to the extension data dictionary

            JToken e;

            if(_additionalData.TryGetValue("requests/duration", out e)){
                endValue = e.ToObject<DataPointer>();
            }
        }
        public Segment()
        {
            _additionalData = new Dictionary<string, JToken>();
        }
    }

    public class Value
    {
        public DateTime start { get; set; }
        public DateTime end { get; set; }
        public string interval { get; set; }
        public List<Segment> segments { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public Value value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, you're option seems to work fine. However, I'd need to add an if-check for each endpoint that is called (and there are quite a few) because of the TryGetValue containing a string that is different for each request.

Comment: Right, in that case you could just get the first value from the dictionary...